# combine multiple tracesource filters in app.config

Tags: c#, logging, app-config, .net, tracesource

I want to configure a FileTraceListeners in my application, that ignores 'verbose' level messages but logs 'information' level and above as well as 'start' and 'stop' events.

Everything is configured within the app.config file.
However I cannot find the correct syntax for combining these different trace levels. 
[The Syntax for filters is explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229326.aspx).

Using a single filter for 'information' will correctly filter out everything that is not 'information', 'warning' 'error' or 'critical'. However I also want to include 'start' and 'stop' events.

I tried using 2 filters :

```xml
<filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Information"/>
<filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="ActivityTracing"/>
```

I tried combining the initializeDate

with commas:
`initializeData="Information,ActivityTracing"`

or semicolons  `initializeData="Information;ActivityTracing"`

everything will just cause a syntax error.

How do I combine these two filters inside app.config?

(I am using the native .net 3.5 logging libraries and do not wish to change to log4net or another framework at this point.)

Answer (score 2):

My code looks like:

```
<filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter"   initializeData="Warning,ActivityTracing"/>
```

and its works.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to use the `<filter>` but recently setup something similar and was successful by using the `<switches>` and `<sources>` elements.  Here's how I did it:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
   <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2" />
   <sources>
     <source name="SyncService" switchName="infoactivity">
       <listeners>
         <clear />
         <add name="file" />
       </listeners>
     </source>
   </sources>
   <switches>
     <add name="none" value="Off" />
     <add name="infoactivity" value="Information, ActivityTracing" />
     <...>
   </switches>
   <sharedListeners>
     <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
          initializeData="sync.log" />
   </sharedListeners>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

Just change the `switchName` value to one of the defined switches to get the appropriate level of logging.

The code used a single static TraceSource wrapped up in a LogEvent smart enum class (I think I found an example on one of Jon Skeet's answers once).

```
public class LogEvent {
  public static readonly LogEvent SyncStart = new LogEvent(1, 
    "Sync Service started on {0}", TraceEventType.Start);
  public static readonly LogEvent SyncStop = new LogEvent(99, 
    "Sync Service stopped on {0}", TraceEventType.Stop);
  public static readonly LogEvent SyncError = new LogEvent(501, 
    "\r\n=============\r\n{0}\r\n==============\r\n", TraceEventType.Error);
  // etc

  private readonly int id;
  private readonly string format;
  private readonly TraceEventType type;
  private static readonly TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("SyncService");

  private LogEvent(int id, string format, TraceEventType type)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.format = format;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public void Log(params object[] data)
  {
    var message = String.Format(format, data);
    trace.TraceEvent(type, id, message);
  }
}
```

and in the service code I liberally sprinkled in logging statements

```
LogEvent.SyncStart.Log(DateTime.Now);
LogEvent.SyncError.Log("What the??? -- " + e.Message);
LogEvent.SyncStop.Log(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

It says here that they can be bitwise combined: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.sourcelevels%28v=vs.90%29).

Have you tried `initializeData="Information|ActivityTracing"`?

Comment: Thanks, it's a good Idea. Sadly, this also causes a ConfigurationErrorsException: "Could not create System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter". I think the initializeData is simply passed to the constructor as a string

Comment: Have you tried using 2 listeners?


    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="prueba1" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">
        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Information"/>
      </add>
      <add name="prueba2" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener">
        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="ActivityTracing"/>
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>

Comment: This may work for ConsoleTraceListeners (not sure), but two FileTraceListeners cannot write to the same file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.  I eventually tried just putting in the decimal value for the bitwise combination of the TraceEventType values I wanted.  It worked.  In my case I wanted Critical, Error, Information and Warn to go to one listener.  I set the value to 1 | 2 | 8 | 4 = 15.  I had another listener I wanted just Verbose going to so I set the value to 16.  I then set the source's switch to 16 | 15 = 31.

example (snippet):

```
<filter type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="15"/>

<switches>
    <add name="sourceSwitch" value="31"/>
</switches>
```

Thanks,
Nick